# How to make jeea.cls compatible with my document?

Tags: document-classes

I have a following problem. I need to format my .tex file using jeea.cls class. My file is working good, unless I rewrite `\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{article}` to
`\documentclass[article, notheorem]{jeea}`. Unfortunately Journal of the European Economic Association (JEEA) requires to format .tex using this class (hint: publish rather somewhere else).

I got bilion of errors in my TeXstudio. The problem seems to be in importing figures. I use
`\usepackage{subfigure}` in my main.tex. I got an error: `Extra \fi. \usepackage`. What does it mean? How can I fix it please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you would have a better chance of an answer if you provided a link to the class and a small but complete document that shows the error (if you are getting an error on a usepackage line your example does not need to be very long or include any text)

Comment: I tried the files in https://static.primary.prod.gcms.the-infra.com/static/site/jeea/document/Instruction-to-Authors.zip?node=3e1f5eeed27c77b809c8&version=265119:5ac07f9d6be44a8bd681  and  `\documentclass{jeea}\usepackage{subfigure}\begin{document}\end{document}` runs without error